# How to invert colors in the image sequence editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I want to create a multiply style replace effect but the reversed color scheme. easiest way I can think of doing this is to invert the colours of the strip I am working with, but I cant find out how to do so. In this image, I would like the back to be the fill of the text and the text to be black. [image]

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 6):

Just add a Curve Modifier to the Strip and "invert" the diagonal line by inserting two points top-left and bottom-right:

[image: Inverted Curve Modifier]